# Why am I not able to print the value of this variable in the debugger?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, debugging, gdb

I have a property of my class called position, which I'm trying to access with self.position.

I get:

```
(gdb) po self.position
There is no member named position.
```

But I set my breakpoint at the for loop in the following block. It definitely has a value:

```
- (IBAction)backFiftyWords:(UIButton *)sender {
    self.position = @([self.position intValue] - 50);

    NSString *wordsToBeShown = @"";

    for (int i = 0; i < [self.numberOfWordsShown intValue]; i++) {
```

It's an NSNumber.

Comment: For whatever it's worth, GDB is deprecated in Xcode in favor of LLDB. Is there a reason you're using GDB?

Comment: http://www.tuaw.com/2013/06/05/devjuice-10-8-4-and-the-ios-simulator/

Comment: Does `po [self position]` work?

Comment: Yes. That is a terribly misleading error message. Gah. I miss you, lldb.

Comment: At least according to the release notes, that hang was fixed in the recent Xcode 4.6.3 update. I've been doing Mac development exclusively for a few months and never saw the problem myself...

Comment: There is an Xcode update out that (I think) fixes the hanging issue.

Comment: Are you using XCode 4.6.3 ? I am seeing these issues since I updated to this version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use

```
po [self position]
```

Dot syntax doesn't work well with GDB.  Upgrading to LLDB/LLVM is a good idea as well.

You can also:

```
NSLog(@"%@", self.position);
```

In your code.  Or create a breakpoint and edit it, add this is an expression:

```
expr (void)NSLog(@"%@", self.position)
```

See this link for more info: http://www.raywenderlich.com/28289/debugging-ios-apps-in-xcode-4-5